# Two z3 solvers with same assertions give different satisfiability output

Tags: z3, smt

I am playing around with Java Z3 API for a research problem and I am really confused about how this is happening:

I create a `Solver` object and add a number of assertions, and repeatedly call the `check()` method, adding additional assertions each time, until it returns `UNSATISFIABLE`. Once it does, I call the `getAssertions()` method on the original `Solver` object and add all the assertions to a new `Solver` object creating using the same `Context` object using `mkSolver()`. When I call `check()` on the new `Solver` object, it returns `SATISFIABLE`.

How can two different `SOLVER` objects with identical assertions and parameters be different in terms of satisfiablity? I'm not sure about the the models are used for evaluating satisfiability.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Java API. But for `get-assertions` to work in regular SMT-Lib, you have to explicitly tell the solver to produce these assertions first. See page 56 of http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf. Perhaps when you do `getAssertions` you merely get an empty list since you haven't told the solver to produce them first? I'd start by checking if the number of assertions you get is a reasonable one.

Comment: Yes. I'm doing that. They have the exact same assertions

Comment: If you think this is a bug, please submit a self-contained, fully reproducible example to the Z3 issue tracker: https://github.com/z3prover/z3